# Lightroom and Incorrect Keyword Count

Tags: lightroom, keywords

I'm using Adobe Lightroom CC.

In the Keyword List panel, I have a keyword that indicates that there are seven photos in the library with that keyword. However, if I click on the arrow to the right of the keyword and number, I get "No photos match the filter."

Any idea how to correct the keyword count?

Comment: Are you sure you are not restraining what is displayed to a subfolder ? Are any other filter activated ?

Comment: When you select the arrow beside a keyword in the keyword list, you are applying a filter on the entire library. But I made sure I was selecting the entire library just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I did what I probably should have done in the first place, which is search the Adobe support forums. When I did, I found [someone had experienced this problem before](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1684060?q=keywords%20number).

Turns out, it was photos that were collapsed in stacks.

[Can't yet mark my answer as correct.]